# identify: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so.62: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.3)

Tags: centos, imagemagick

ImageMagick 6.5.4-10

when i used identify 53d74fe9e807ba7d78000001.jpg

the console output:

identify: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so.62: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.3)

who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Because this centos miss some package,when i install them , the problem was sloved

The solution:

yum install libpng libpng-devel libtiff libtiff-devel libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-devel